# xml sel -t -m does not work for me at all

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I have the following file log.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<EntryList xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/">
  <Entries>
    <RankedEntry>
      <Entry>
        <id>1</id>
        <code1>001</code1>
        <displayName>Entry 1</displayName>
        <code2>003</code2>
        <code3>0100000000000005203</code3>
        <actualName>Entry Number 1</actualName>
        <entryType>1</entryType>
        <metaScore>1</metaScore>
        <usage>81</usage>
      </Entry>
      <factor>30.738496780395508</factor>
      <virtualFactor>45.738494873046875</virtualFactor>
    </RankedEntry>
    <RankedEntry>
      <Entry>
        <id>2</id>
        <code1>001</code1>
        <displayName>Entry 2</displayName>
        <code2>003</code2>
        <code3>0200000000000005203</code3>
        <actualName>Entry Number 2</actualName>
        <entryType>26</entryType>
        <metaScore>1</metaScore>
        <usage>61</usage>
      </Entry>
      <factor>40.738496780395508</factor>
      <virtualFactor>55.738494873046875</virtualFactor>
    </RankedEntry>
    <RankedEntry>
      <Entry>
        <id>3</id>
        <code1>001</code1>
        <displayName>Entry 3</displayName>
        <code2>003</code2>
        <code3>0300000000000005203</code3>
        <actualName>Entry Number 3</actualName>
        <entryType>3</entryType>
        <metaScore>1</metaScore>
        <usage>41</usage>
      </Entry>
      <factor>50.738496780395508</factor>
      <virtualFactor>65.738494873046875</virtualFactor>
    </RankedEntry>
  </Entries>    
</EntryList>
```

On Window 7 using xmlstarlet 1.6.1 if I run the following command,

xml sel -t -m "/EntryList/Entries/RankedEntry/Entry/entryType" -v "." log.xml

Expected result is:

```
1
26
3
```

Actual: 
But I do not get anything back

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

**You have to account for the namespace.  Define a namespace prefix using the XMLStarlet `-N` option:**

```
  -N <name>=<value>         - predefine namespaces (name without 'xmlns:')
                              ex: xsql=urn:oracle-xsql
                              Multiple -N options are allowed.
```

**Then this XMLStarlet command:**

```
xml sel -N s=http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ -t -v "/s:EntryList/s:Entries/s:RankedEntry/s:Entry/s:entryType" log.xml
```

**Will produce the requested output:**

```
1
26
3
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that works but has made my xmlstarlet command much more difficult to read.

Comment: If you have a recent version (1.5 and above I think), the namespace prefixes are picked up from the document (with the default one binding to `_`). So you could just do `xml sel -t -v "/_:EntryList/_:Entries/_:RankedEntry/_:Entry/_:entryType" log.xml`

Answer (score 1):

Starting with version 1.2.1 you can use de default namespace `_`
(drop the `-N` argument)

```
xml sel -t -v "/_:EntryList/_:Entries/_:RankedEntry/_:Entry/_:entryType" log.xml
```

As explained [here](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch05.html):

> 1.3. A More Convenient Solution
>
> XML documents can also use different namespace prefixes, on any
>   element in the document. In order to handle namespaces with greater
>   ease, XMLStarlet (versions 1.2.1+) will use the namespace prefixes
>   declared on the root element of the input document. The default
>   namespace will be bound to the prefixes "_" and "DEFAULT" (in versions
>   1.5.0+).

Comment: Awesome answer, saved my sanity, sorry I can only award 1 point for this!

Comment: **WARNING:** Don't try to use such XPaths anywhere else as this oddity is *not* part of the XPath standard.